# WPF - Object's list to its own comboBoxColumn in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I am trying to bind List to datagrid, where each Address has its own ID and List. It means that Address1 has more options (Street1, Street2), as Address2 has Street3,Street4,Street5 and so on.

So each row in datagrid has different combobox - List.

I tried several different options, but with no success. This is the Address class:

```
public class Address
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> streets { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mira, please provide more code if it's possible because the thing you gave us is just a piece of model which is not helpfull at all. I'd like to see how have you tried bind this addresses on the xaml side. Sorry to ask silly question but I don't know either if you have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface etc.

Comment: Let us know what have you tried. add `XAML` of your `DataGrid` you are trying in the Question.